# Mod Perl on RHEL 7

Tags: redhat, httpd, perl, rhel7

I for the life of me can not find the mod_perl package for RHEL 7. There is no package remotely called mod_perl, and google does not help. I am trying to get Redmine Git Hosting setup, but I need to load a perl module in the config file (using PerlLoadModule).

Ideas?

```
yum install mod_perl
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
This system is receiving updates from RHN Classic or Red Hat Satellite.
No package mod_perl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 3):

mod_perl is no longer in base but it IS available in EPEL 7; so my suggestion is you get it from there. Note that EPEL 7 is still in 'beta'.

http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/SRPMS/repoview/mod_perl.html
http://developerblog.redhat.com/2014/02/20/rhel-7-beta-extra-packages/

..and I'm the one who wrote the blog post mentioned by Jakov.

Comment: The URL is not working...

Answer (score 2):

RHEL 7 uses Apache 2.4, and there is still no mod_perl package for it. mod_perl was on a list of removed packages in beta version. More info:

https://www.huntingbears.nl/2013/12/17/no-mod_perl-in-rhel-7-and-centos-7/

What I would suggest is to get Fedora 20 or 19 src.rpm from pkgs.org, spin up development RHEL 7 box and rebuild package for RHEL 7.